# Curvature and rigid movements

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, rigid-transformation

I am getting stuck on a problem that should actually be very easy.

Let $\alpha(t)$ be a birregular curve in 3D space, and $M$ a rigid movement. Let's define $\beta = M \circ \alpha $.

The question is to find the curvature of $\beta$ in terms of the curvature of $\alpha$.

By its definition, the curvature is the module of the second derivative of the curve.

Then, $k_\beta = |\beta''|=|(M \circ \alpha)''| = |((M'\circ \alpha)\alpha')'| = |(M''\circ \alpha)\alpha'^2 + (M'\circ \alpha)\alpha'')| $

Since $M$ is an affine transformation, its derivatives are all equal to the underlying vectorial transformation $\hat M$ of module $1$, so

$k_\beta = |\hat M (\alpha'^2 + \alpha'')|=|(\alpha'^2 + \alpha'')|$

But there is no way this is correct - in particular, $M$ could have been the identity transformation, and thus the curvature should stay the same.

Why is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: Dear @Jsevillamol, I get $|\beta''|=|(M\alpha')'|=|M(\alpha'')|=|\alpha''|$. The last identity is consequence of $M$ being a rigid movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $M$ is an affine transformation, its *first* derivative is equal to the underlying linear map. In particular, the first derivative is constant,  *so the higher derivatives vanish*. Thus $$(M'' \circ \alpha)\alpha'^2 + (M'\circ \alpha)\alpha'' = \hat M\alpha''$$ as desired.